# How to share same data one action method to other action method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

1. When i call my admin controller- Index Action method will get all the user details
2. when i want select particular user again i dont want to hit the DB.

both action method same controller and i'm using model popup for display details.

**My Question**
I dont want to use entity framework.
- when admin form load i will get all the user details this is Index Action Method
-based on user id i need to display particular user so again i dont want hit to the DB already i'm having all the user details. that details how to get another action method?

i can remember asp.net i used session to share the data globally. like that asp.net mvc is possible? please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, session is allowed. But it is advised that you shouldn't use Session and may be store user data in hidden html or JSON object and then send to another action

Comment: How does your view look like? If you are displaying Users data in table and it contains all required info present in table related to user then you can get data of particular user using jquery.

Comment: Thanks friends for quick reply. what i'm asking not only user data, i want avoid to hit database every time, first time when page load i will get the data and i need to store some where else then whenever i want i need to access. is there any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you're looking for a cache mechanism. For simple scenarios, I use a simple static variable, but I keep it in a separated class. Let's suppose you have a User class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could create a class like this:

```
public static class UserCacheService
{
    private static IEnumerable<User> _users;
    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    public static IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (_users == null)
            {
                using (var db = new MyNiceDbContext())
                {
                    _users = db.Users.ToList();
                }
            }
            return _users;
        }
    }

    public static void InvalidateCache()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            _users = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can get your *shared* users in any action, of any controller like this:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // the first time, it'll need to get users from DB (e.g with Entity Framework)
        var users = UserCacheService.GetUsers();
        return View();
    }

}
```

The first time, the `_users` in your `UserCacheService` will be null, and as expected, it'll need to load users from database. However, the next time it won't, no matter if you are using another controller:

```
public class AnotherController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(string userId)
    {
        // now, it won't load from DB anymore, because _users is already populated...
        var users = UserCacheService.GetUsers();
        var currentUser = users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            // do something with the user...
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

There are times when unfortunately your `_users` will become `null` again, for example when you restart your **ApplicationPool** in IIS, but `UserCacheService` is already prepared for fetching database once if that's the case.

Be careful about three things:

1. Whenever you keep data in memory (like `_users`), you are consuming
   your **server's memory**, which might be limited. Don't start trying to
   keep everything in memory, only data you know you'll need everytime.
2. Whenever you update something in your users, like a name, an address or something else, since the `_users` will not get from database everytime, you need to call the `UserCacheService.InvalidateCache()` method, in order to force the next call to load again from database, thus making sure you have `_users` up to date.
3. This only works for simplistic scenarios. If you have your application distributed in two or more servers, this won't work, as each server has it's own memory and they can't share it out of the box. That's when you would look forward for something like Redis. Though, I don't think it's your case here.

Comment: @SENA you're welcome. If it works as you exptected, don't forget marking it as accepted, so we can know it worked.

Comment: Hi Alisson, Its working fine. thank you so much. and one more clarification when i want to call this method. public static void InvalidateCache()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            _users = null;
        }
    }

Comment: @SENA whenever you update user details in the database.